# Is there anything like HTTP exists?

Tags: http

I would like to send a HTTP 302 redirect response (it redirects to an other domain other server). However *before* I send the response I would like to check if the resource I am going to redirect is exits or not. If not then redirect to an alternative resource and so on. *The other domain other server is out of my control.*

An obvious solution would be to send a request to the other domain other server for the resource and if I got error especially HTTP 404 then conclude the resource does not exist. However this solutions seems to be wasting both server resources and bandwidth.

So that's why my question: Is there anything like HTTP exist? I mean a query to ask a server if a resource exist or not.

Comment: You may be looking for the `HEAD` method verb - it means "send me only the header for this resource, not the entire thing"

Comment: Thanks. Looking now.

Comment: You can also cache the result of the check for a while, so you do not need to check for each request. Of course this increases the risk that the forwarding fails, but reduces latency greatly for most requests.

Comment: @jofel: Sure I am using a dictionary of Url-s

Comment: @g.pickardou Your question looked to me, as if you want to check for every HTTP 302 response all times the existing of the target beforehand without any caching - which would cost quite much resources.